# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when compiling and linking projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I recently made the change to Visual Studio 2015 from Visual Studio 2012 as my compiler for my c++ projects. After making this change I have noticed that visual studio will frequently hang in the build process.

This never occurred with Visual Studio 2012. The hangups are at random points and do not occur at the same build points in my projects.

When I ran VS in administrator mode and got all of the cl.exe's and link.exe's to appear as command prompts I was able to see when they hung. And there were no errors thrown or anything.

The only way I have successfully worked around this issue is by setting Visual Studio's build process to only process one project at a time and use only one compilation simultaneously. However I cant maintain this as my build time is somewhere around 3-4 hours (Yes, this is a HUGE project).

Comment: Do you have steps to reliably reproduce the problem? If not, you may want to try narrowing it down even farther before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Win64 hangs during solution build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146625/visual-studio-2015-win64-hangs-during-solution-build/37752155#37752155).  I posted an answer there.  In short, there may be a patch that resolves the issue:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51161