# Visual Studio 2015 stuck at linking, some endless loop, huge data reads

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Recently my Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) started getting stuck at final linking in Debug configuration mode. Out of a sudden, it starts a huge endless I/O read (as you can see I waited 10 minutes until 730 GB, then I manually stopped it)
[image: 213]
The memory usage is normal, project is rather big, but that I/O read bytes should be minimal.

I saw a lot of similar posts on stack overflow (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146625/visual-studio-2015-win64-hangs-during-solution-build)), but all different / not helping. Also tried changing incremental linking, same.

This seems to happen when I add some random code. For example a simple `if this, do that`. Doesn't matter how many times I try to compile, it gets stuck 100%. If I delete that code (or add even more code), it starts linking again everytime, so this is not a random issue happening every now and then. It either happens with current code or it doesn't.

In Release mode it doesn't happen. Maybe too many symbols?

Any thoughts where should I start investigating this? I already tried enabling full verbose output, still not useful. It gets stuck out of a sudden, with no apparent connection with the last task from the output window

Comment: Have you tried nuking your working directory files & restoring everything from version control?  PDBs and other build artifacts sometimes go wonky.

Comment: Yes, I did that using both possible methods: clean solution from visual studio (which already clears those files) and new, fresh build directory